# Catch true statement from if condition with multiple statements

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the true statement from $this if condition:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
$c = 7;

if ($a == 3 || $b == 4 || $c == 7) {
    echo "The true statement was: ";
}
```

I expect to get this output:

```
The true statement was: 7
```

Is it possible to do this in PHP?

Or better to say how can i check which statement has triggered the if condition?

Comment: Possible with multiple checks. What if `$month == 4` and `$year == 2017` both are `true`? What would be the output?

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to get....but without multiple ifs inside....is that possible?

Comment: @Webbanditten I am open for discussion what do you don't understand?

Comment: I guess not possible without multiple checks.

Comment: Yeah probably....because as soon as one is true it will get inside that if. And i will not be able to check others...but maybe i can get that one which has triggered it to get in???

Comment: You can use a loop to do that but multiple `if`s will be simpler.

Comment: What would be the output instead of `The true statements are: 2017`

Comment: Yess....it's not about the date....it's about the statement that caused the whole IF condition to be true?!

Comment: What if more than one condition triggers the if statement?

Comment: It will get only the first one which is true! That is how if works! As soon as one is true it will get inside...and then you got that one!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only ever show 1 true statement because of how the if works:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
$c = 7;

if (($t = $a) ==3 || ($t = $b) == 4 || ($t=$c) == 7) {
   echo "The true statement was: $t";
}
```

What happens here is it sets `$t` to each variable and then checks if the assignment result (which is the value) was successful. Since this is an `||` then it stops at the first success and so `$t` will have the last compared value.

Comment: this is very interesting i need to test it

Comment: I get an error, try to run that code please here: http://phptester.net/

Comment: It works perfectly...it will show exactly that statement which caused the IF to be true! I hope you will get more votes on this because it is a really good answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can't without multiple conditions. Whatever answer you will get here eg:

- Inline if statements
- Wrap in a function
- Condition result assignment in the condition
- Switch
- Loops

etc. Will always require you to have multiple conditions.

If you don't mind multiple conditions and just looking for most elegant way to write it, thats another question and we can help.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OK I have updated my question....is it possible to catch which statement made the if condition to be true?

Comment: @SougataBose How is that not answering the question? He asked if it is possible, the answer is no, its not - read the full answer above

Comment: @lewis4u I don't see any update to the question. Bottom line is, you cannot "catch" what condition "triggered" the IF statement

Comment: @Tom, there is no need to get hyper man. *Is it possible to do this in PHP?
Or better to say how can i check which statement has triggered the if condition?*

Comment: @lewis4u it is assingment in condition which I mentioned above, but yes it does work

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
$day = 1;
$month = 3;
$year = 2017;

$str = "The true statements are: " . ($day == 3 ? "$day, " : "") . ($month == 4 ? "$month, " : "") . ($year == 2017 ? "$year, " : "");
echo substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - 2);
?>
```

If I understand correctly, this should work.

The `strlen($str) -2` is to remove the trailing ", ".

Comment: As I understand, the statement should read a list a of which ones trigger the if statement? With this example it will list more if there are more to list. I assumed that multiple could be listed since the `echo` says "statements" using the plural.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with boolean variables:

```
$day = 1;
$month = 3;
$year = 2017;

$cday = $day == 3;
$cmonth = $month == 4;
$cyear = $year == 2017;

if ($cday || $cmonth || $cyear) {
    echo "The true statements are: ";
    if($cday) echo "$day<br>\n";
    if($cmonth) echo "$month<br>\n";
    if($cyear) echo "$year<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help -

```
// actual values
$day = 1;
$month = 3;
$year = 2017;

// values & variable names to check
$checks = array(
'day' => 1, 
'month' => 4, 
'year' => 2017,
);
// Loop through the checks
foreach($checks as $check => $value) {
   // compare values
   if($$check == $value) {
       // output and stop looping
       echo "The true statement was: $check -> $value";
       break;
   }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/766935)